# Is it Ok to have a UserControl property inside a ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Is it Ok to have a UserControl property inside a ViewModel?

Does this not violate the principles of MVVM?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No it's not ok. You should never mix view model with view. You should have another view model property and if the property type varies `DataTemplate` to each `DataType` in your view where you specify which `UserControl` to use for each view model type

Comment: Does this question even make sense? How can you ever have a **user control property** inside a view model? 

I think you have asked this question without trying out some code. You can't do that anyway. Instead you can bind properties of user control to properties in **ViewModel**

Comment: But if i can bind properties of user control to properties in ViewModel, what kind of type should those properties be(in ViewModel)?I want to bind a UserControl property inside a  ViewModel to Datacontext.Context property of my Window for to be able to change UserControl in runtime.Thanks for help.